# Where can I access docker file system on windows

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I installed docker on windows 7 by creating a virtual machine (oracle VM virtualbox). Now I am creating my own images of tomcat,using base image from public repository, and installing a simple war file. I can access tomcat homepage but I can't access the application. Below is my DockerFile

```
FROM tomcat:7.0
ADD tomcat-users.xml $CATALINA_HOME/conf
RUN mkdir /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample
COPY sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample.war
```

So my questions are

1. How can I access the manager page of tomcat. I don't have the user and pwd of the one that I used (tomcat 7.0)?
2. How can I access the tomcat image file system on my windows or the virtual machine, similar to we use tomcat locally?
3. How can I access Docker file system on my windows or virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not Wrong, you cannot access docker file system on Windows because Docker  is installed on a Virtual machine(docker toolbox). If you want to access docker file system you must to get inside the Operating System into the Virtual machine and later looking for docker file system once in.

Now, if you want to access to tomcat try to use the ip address of the virtual machine, and be sure that the port of tomcat is accesible from outside.

Plus, Access Tomcat files, you can use [Volume Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)